# ORA00906 Missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
create table Klient 
(
   ID_klient            integer                        not null,
   ID_pobocka           integer                        not null,
   ID_pracovnik         integer                        null,
   hodnota_rs           integer                        not null,
   jmeno_klient         char(25)                       not null,
   prijmeni_klient      char(25)                       not null,
   pohlavi_klient       char(1)                        not null
    constraint CKC_POHLAVI_KLIENT_KLIENT check (pohlavi_klient in ('Z','M')),
   vek                  integer                        not null,
   segment_klient       varchar(20)                    not null,
   constraint PK_KLIENT primary key clustered (ID_klient)
);
```

Missing a left parenthesis somewhere, can't seem to find anything missing though. Anyone got a better eye?

908. 00000 - "missing left parenthesis"

Comment: Please note the code formatting button when posting the question. I've formatted the question for you now so it's easier to read. Also please always include the exact error message with the question.

Comment: Thanks, was just doing so!

Comment: Put a comma (,) before constraint CKC_POHLAVI_KLIENT_KLIENT and you are good to go ... :)

Comment: That did not solve the main problem, but I missed that nevertheless, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's expecting opening paranthesis instead of `clustered` in primary key constraint definition, could you try the following:

```
create table Klient 
(
   ID_klient            integer                        not null,
   ID_pobocka           integer                        not null,
   ID_pracovnik         integer                        null,
   hodnota_rs           integer                        not null,
   jmeno_klient         char(25)                       not null,
   prijmeni_klient      char(25)                       not null,
   pohlavi_klient       char(1)                        not null
    constraint CKC_POHLAVI_KLIENT_KLIENT check (pohlavi_klient in ('Z','M')),
   vek                  integer                        not null,
   segment_klient       varchar(20)                    not null,
   constraint PK_KLIENT primary key (ID_klient)
);
```

Comment: That was it! Why was it so?

Comment: that's because `clustered` is not  a part of primary key syntax (documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html)).

Comment: That got generated from Power Designer, weird! Thanks Darshan

Answer (score 0):

Its not about parenthesis, its missing a comma:

```
    create table Klient 
    (
       ID_klient            integer                        not null,
       ID_pobocka           integer                        not null,
       ID_pracovnik         integer                        null,
       hodnota_rs           integer                        not null,
       jmeno_klient         char(25)                       not null,
       prijmeni_klient      char(25)                       not null,
       pohlavi_klient       char(1)                        not null,
        constraint CKC_POHLAVI_KLIENT_KLIENT check (pohlavi_klient in ('Z','M')),
       vek                  integer                        not null,
       segment_klient       varchar(20)                    not null,
       constraint PK_KLIENT primary key clustered (ID_klient)
    );
```